# Editing coordinates of CityGML Building?

Tags: fme-form, citygml

I'm looking for the most efficient method of editing coordinates for a building in a CityGML file. My setup:

1. I have a base CityGML file with a set of buildings in a defined area of the community I'm working in.
2. I am trying to merge a new building from a different CityGML file to my base CityGML file.

My initial idea was to change the coordinates of the new building by editing the CityGML file in order to match it to the base CityGML file, and then simply copy and paste the appropriate parts of the CityGML file into the base CityGML file.

However, I discovered that because every face of the building has its own coordinates, this would be a very tedious process. I have to be able to iterate the location of the new building in the base CityGML file, so I'm looking for the best method of doing this.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I am confused with your question. Do you want to edit the coordinates of an existing building in a CityGML file, or do you want to add a building from the second CityGML file into the first one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use scripting languages, then it is just a matter of parsing and manipulating XML and implementing whatever computations that need to be performed. This is definitely less tedious then hand-editing.

Comment: +1 Doubly true if you're going to be doing anything similar in the future.